# Spring url tags with jsessionid

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a jsp with the following (relevant) setup:

```
<s:url value="/res" var="res_url" />

<link href="${res_url}/less/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
<link href="${res_url}/less/responsive.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
...
```

Ive noticed a problem with using this technique, in that on the first page load of a new session my `res_url` variable will have `";jsessionid=xxxxxxxxx"` appended. In this case that means the id appears in the middle of my stylesheet URL and therefore the stylesheets are not loaded.

I realize that I'm probably not using the URL tag in the way its intended, and that you can include param tags inside the URL tag to get around this, but I don't like the idea of it and think the way i did it was much cleaner. Is it possible to somehow tell it to ignore the jsessionid? Or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is

```
<link href="<s:url value="/res/less/bootstrap.less"/>" rel="stylesheet/less">
<link href="<s:url value="/res/less/responsive.less"/>" rel="stylesheet/less">
```

I don't see what any simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the benefit of using Spring's URL tag over the standard JSTL tag. What about

```
<c:url value="/res/less/bootstrap.less" var="lessBootstrap" />
<link href="${lessBootstrap}" rel="stylesheet/less">
```

If you want to define the `/res/less` path in a variable instead of repeating it you may do this like this:

```
<c:set var="resDir" value="/res/less" scope="request" />
```